# GoogleMock: ошибка MTd_StaticDebug при сборке проекта

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, google-mock

Собрал библиотеки из фреймворка для тестирования `GoogleMock` gmock.lib, подключил к проекту, но при сборке получаю ошибку:

> error LNK2038: обнаружено несоответствие для "RuntimeLibrary": значение "MTd_StaticDebug" не соответствует значению "MDd_DynamicDebug" в main.obj

С чем это может быть связано и как это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Зайдите в настройки вашего проекта **Configuration Properties-> C/C++ -> Code Generation.** И обратите внимание на настройку **Runtime Libriry**  и вместо **Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)** выставите **Multi-threaded (/MT)** Либо линкуйте MD `версию gmock.lib`

Comment: Только это настройка `Runtime library` а не `Struct Member Alignment` и настройку лучше оставить `Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)` и перевести на нее gmock.

Comment: Поправил ответ.

Comment: Если ставить /MTd, тогда при линковке проектов на Qt будут статически линковаться библиотеки Qt, а это нехорошо. Как перекомпилировать gmock под /MDd? Что будет на выходе? DLL? Я пытался, но возникла проблема, которую я уже не могу вспомнить.